# Refreshing DOM between click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the click event:

```
$('#undoAll').click(function(){
    $('#prospectTable tbody tr td a:not(.invisible)').each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    })
});
```

which calls individual click events.

The inner click events in the above code make changes to the DOM. I would like these changes to appear after each individual inner click event so the user can see that things are happening (the outer click event can take up to 30 seconds to complete).

Unfortunately, no changes to the DOM are made until all the click events are processed.

Is there anything I can do to force the DOM to refresh after each inner click?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thats a lot of screen rerendering.  why not let it naturally redrawn / refresh when it wants and be happy?

Comment: It depends on what those click handlers do. You can consider using deferred objects + `setTimeout`.

Comment: You have a UI action that takes _30 seconds_???

Comment: @Methletics - I can have up to 200 links. Rather than force the user to click each and every one I want him to be able to click one link which in turn will click the other links. I would also like the DOM to refresh after each click in the same way it would if he indeed did click each link. The 200 separate events can take up to 30 seconds to complete. I don't expect this to be a common occurrence, just a worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of experimenting the following seems to achieve precisely the desired effect.

```
$('#undoAll').click
(
    function()
    {
        if($('#prospectTable tbody tr td a:not(.invisible)').length > 0)
        {
            $('#prospectTable tbody tr td a:not(.invisible)').first().click();
            setTimeout
            (
                function()
                {
                    $('#undoAll').click();
                }, 1
            );
        };
    }
);
```

The issue appears to be that there is no redrawing or refreshing of the DOM until the click event is complete. The setTimeout allows one click event to end (allowing a redraw) while setting up another.